# Weird light around my meshes in Cycles rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

[image][image]

What could be source of this weird orange light around cookies and what could be fix?

I am using Cycles render and CPU(I have old GPU which is not supported in Blender 2.9 anymore).

I am talking about orange light between cookies, where my mouse cursor is on the 2nd image.

I accidentally applied subdivision surface modifier so those cookies have a lot vertices, but there are no other modifiers active.
I am using 3 lights, 2 area and point, but even if I disable them, this orange color can still be seen. Lights are white.
For plate I am using Porcelain from BlenderKit addon, but even if I disable plate that orange color is still there.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question. It would help if we knew more about the scene. Start by showing us the material you are using for the cookies.

Comment: More info to add: what kind of lights are you using? What is the world background? Are you using a GPU for rendering (by default you would not be)? If so, what make and model? What are the material setups for the plate and the cookies? Are you using a third party image texture or a procedural texture? What coordinates are you using for that texture? Are there any modifiers on the cookies?

Comment: Can you circle exactly what you are talking about?

Comment: Umm, there's no mouse cursor in the second image. I think it is disabled in the screenshot program :-D

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using a texture to make the cookies look dusty with faked normals or bump-mapping (not bad, BTW), and are mapping whatever texture via UV coordinates. I also assume that the orange light you are talking about is the bright orange ridging on the edges of some cookies.

The fact that this is at a corner and seems to be in a straight line makes me think this is a texture mapping problem, and that the normal changing is not happening there, which leaves those parts of the cookies appearing perfectly smooth, and thus brighter.

Check that those edges of the cookies are properly UV mapped and not scrunched into some corner, and if you are using an image texture, check that the image node's mapping setting is set to "repeat" and not "clip."

Separately, one cookie that is sitting flat is penetrating the plate, thus making it look unnaturally bright, because in real life light gets trapped between the edge of the cookie and the plate, making it dark. This is called "Ambient Occlusion," and can be faked in EEVEE, though Cycles should do it by itself.

To help you position the cookie correctly, use Wireframe view and then go into orthographic from the side.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I am having problem with stacking cookies, somehow when I change anything there is overlapping somewhere, is there any more precise(automatic) way?
About UV mapping, it is mess. A lot of overlapping and since SubModifier is applied there is lot of face triangles and it is hard to clean them up. Can I somehow automatic sort them so they are not overlapping?
I edited question, sorry for the unclear information.

Comment: The stacking is another question, but in short I recommend using the physics engine. I also recommend reading the whole manual from beginning to I-don't-need-this-anymore phase (as opposed to I-am-bored-to-literal-tears phase, which I hit around modifiers but now I love 'em).

Comment: UV mapping is also another question. The short version is that your job in UV mapping is basically to mark seams. If you were trying to wrap the cookie without being able to fold anything, but you had slightly stretchy fabric that could stick together at the edges, how would you do it? Mark seams along the edges, then "select all," and "unwrap."

Comment: Edit: Looking further at the material node setup, I would say the mesh is not manifold or has normals oriented backwards. Maybe add close-ups of the suspect areas in edit mode?

Comment: Hahaha ok thanks for the tip for manual :D
I will post screenshot of the cookie in edit mode, you will see faces are very messy on the part where the lighting is problem. I think it is because of that. Probably better to start cookie from beginning since it is easier to make it again than correcting all those problems